# looking for alternative to polling once per sec in a bash script

Tags: bash, timer, sleep, polling

This code is untested, the aim is to check the size of the output file every 3 secs and kill myprogram if it stops increasing. It should also be killed after 60 secs regardless.

This script will be run multiple times triggered by the events of an overall script.

My question is, id there a more efficient way to achieve the monitoring of the file sizes with out running dozens of 1 sec timers.

Perhaps a script running a master 1 sec timer who's output is piped into all of the file size monitoring scripts as and when they're run?

```
myprogram >> ~/log/$$.txt
pid=!$
filesize='1'
counter='0'
counter2='0'
while ((counter<61))
 do
 ((counter++))
 ((counter2++))
  if (( $counter2 == "3" )) ;
  then
  counter2='0'
  lastfilesize=$filesize
  filesize=$(stat -c%s "~/log/$$.txt")
   if (( $filesize == $lastfilesize )) ;
   then 
   kill $pid
   fi
  fi
 sleep 1
done
 if (( $counter == 61 )) ;
 then
 kill $pid
 fi
exit
```

Comment: If you're only interested in checking every 3 seconds, why not `sleep 3` in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

If you're only interested in checking every 3 seconds, why not sleep 3 in the loop? – Grisha Levit